# How can i add viewportChecker jquery

Tags: jquery

can anyone help me to add viewportChecker on this jquery

**my goal is to add an animation on 4 div class c1, c2, c3, c4** when i scroll down each div class will have their own animation.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    var posts = jQuery('.wk-effect').children();    
    function animateCircle() {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            jQuery(posts[i]).addClass('visible animated bounceInUp');
        } else {
            jQuery(posts[i]).addClass('visible animated fadeInDown');
        }
        i++;
        if (i <= posts.length) {
            startAnimation();
        }
    }    
    function startAnimation() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            animateCircle();}, 1000);
    }    
    posts.addClass('hidden');
    animateCircle(posts);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin if that's easier for you.

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: im not sure how i can integrate that to the current script i have if you can integrate it to above script i would gladly appreciate it..